# convert ascii to integer

Tags: c, int, ascii

I already kown how to convert，but the "while" doesn't stop ,it runs over and over.I don't know why? Is " string !='\0' " doesn't work? Is the char always ended with '\0'?

```
#include <stdio.h>
   int ascii_integer(char *string){
   int result = 0;
  while (string !='\0')
  {
     if (*string >='0' && *string <='9')
     {
        result *= 10;
        result += *string - '0';
     }
     string++;
  }
  return result;
}
int main(){
  char string[] = "12345";
  int result = ascii_integer(string);
  printf("%d\n",result);
}
```

Comment: That's a weirdly indented function.

Comment: `string` is a pointer and won't be 0 if it's pointing to some string

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc - Unless it is the null pointer (on most systems)

Comment: yes I've said that "if it's pointing to some string" and null pointer isn't pointing somewhere (on most systems)

Comment: regarding the line:  while (string !='\0')  this is comparing the pointer rather than what the pointer points to.  a much better line would be:  while (*string != '\0')

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
while (string !='\0')
```

should be

```
while (*string)
```

I am surprised you did not get a warning from the compiler

Comment: I didn't get a warning,I'm confused

Comment: 1. Switch on the warnings. 2. You are comparing the value of a pointer with zero. You want to compare the contents that the pointer points to. i.e. if it is zero or not

Comment: '\0' is the same as 0, which is the same as NULL.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is comparing the pointer to zero instead of de-referencing and comparing a character to zero. In my opinion you are less likely to make that mistake if you choose better variable names and a better loop structure. Here is how I might write that code. I like short.

```
// my preference
int ascii_integer(char *pstring) {
  int result = 0;
  for ( ; *pstring != NULL; ++pstring) {
    if (*pstring >= '0' && *pstring <= '9')
      result = result * 10 + *pstring - '0';
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line
  while (string !='\0')
should be
  while(*string!='\0')
  OR 
  while(*string)

Answer (score 0):

When you typed:

```
while(string != '\0')
```

'\0' is NULL, the symbol with the ascii value of 0, you compared string - which is a pointer - to NULL. It is not NULL, it's pointing somewhere to some content, a string I'd guess.
You should change it to:

```
while(*string != '\0')
```

while the CONTENT (`*`) of that string pointer is not zero, and for shortcut:

```
while(*string)
```

means - while `*string` is TRUE. While it is different from zero.